# Are there benefits to resetting your progression such as prestige?

Tags: helldivers

Do you receive any added perks or benefits by resetting facets of your progression in Helldivers?  I see there are a few ways to do it.

- Reduce rank by 1
- Reset research points
- Reset unlocks
- Reset all progression

Do any of these provide any direct benefit such as how some modern shooters like Call of Duty provide prestige ranking every reset or is it just there in case you want to level up again with another player?

Answer (score 1):

No. The only thing you get is just an opportunity to start from scratch in case you are that kind of a player who loves grinding.